# Is there a limit on API keys (Subsriptions) in Azure API Management Consumption tier?

Tags: azure, api, azure-devops

We're looking to use Azure API Management consumption tier to create an API gateway, but I've read somewhere there is a limit of 500 on the number of API keys you can create. But, I can't see any documentation on it, one way or another.

Does anyone know the truth of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/azure-subscription-service-limits#api-management-limits), The maximum number of subscription (API Keys)per service instance is 500.

[image]

If you would like more than 500. The best approach would be to use premium tier or standard or basic . For non-consumption tiers  don't have any artificial limit as such.

Comment: Thanks for that - very helpful. Seems a bit of an Achilles heel to me - the reason we'd want the Consumption tier is, it is scalable to any amount of usage. But then, limits the number of authenticated users you can have to 500? I wonder why.